# How can i Use BMG CS-09 EVDO Modem in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: cdma

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
```

is shown, but it says modem not detected.

My modem:

- Network type: CDMA 1X-EVDO , USB2.0 Connector
- Quad-band: CDMA 800/1900MHZ

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Use EVDO CDMA Modem in Ubuntu](http://syangjahome.com/use-evdo-cdma-modem-ubuntu/)    (Orginal Post)

[Use EVDO CDMA Modem in Ubuntu](http://blog.computertec.tk/2014/09/use-evdo-cdma-modem-in-ubuntu.html)    (Supporting Post)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is detecting it as mass storage and the driver is not loaded.

For Your device issue following commands:
first find the id of your device issuing `lsusb` command in terminal

```
lsusb
```

If your output looks like this

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
```

Then use `modprobe` to change from USB mass storage to modem or i.e provide driver with following command

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x05c6 product=0x1000
```

After this your modem will be detected, according to your desktop environment use your networkmanager to connect,

To check the status of your device you can issue following command

```
dmesg
```

There will be GSM modem instead of mass storage....

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Download and unzip [config-pack](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11876059/configPack.tar.gz) to `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`
2. Reboot computer.

My modem is active after about one minute.

Original post in [foreign language](http://susiloncuz.blogspot.cz/2013/08/instal-modem-cdmaevdo-di-ubuntu-1304.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. eject the CD-ROM as it automatically got attached

   ```
   eject sr1
   ```
2. modeprobe for kernel provides driver for modem

   ```
   sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x05c6 product=0×6000
   ```
3. WVDIAL utility to connect using our modem, configure it by editing the `/etc/wvdial.conf` with content as below (make sure to change your username and password).

   ```
   [Dialer Defaults]
   Init1 = ATZ
   Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
   Modem Type = Analog Modem
   Baud = 460800
   New PPPD = yes
   Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
   ISDN = 0
   Phone = #777
   Password = YOUR_USERNAME
   Username = YOUR_PASSWORD
   stupid mode = 1
   ```
4. Do step 2, 3 in 1-2 second interval, or Modem will get passive.

[Reference](http://www.megaleecher.net/Linux_And_Internet_Access_Using_EVDO_Modem#axzz43S3XlUu0)