# Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM not shoing in network manager

Tags: usb, network-manager, modem

I have got hold of a USB 3G modem for my travels in a couple of weeks.  I was hoping it was a case of connect and it should show up in Network manager in Ubuntu 16.04 unfortunately nothing.

The only place it seems to show up is if I run `usb-devices` in a terminal

This is the output relating to the modem;

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=05c6 ProdID=1000 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Qualcomm, Incorporated
S:  Product=Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
S:  SerialNumber=351602000025260
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Please help me to get this to work and escape this insanity!

Thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/516354/692175

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply MichaelBay but that didnt work.  The Netowk manager does not show any Mobile Connections even though I have manually sent them up.   I did have a Dell that had integrated 3G and that showed up as "Mobile Connections".   There is just Enable networking and Enable WiFi, sadly after trying that no mention of Mobile Connection even after probling the Kernel

Comment: If so you should [edit] and update your question with what you tried and what were the results, error messages, etc.

Comment: LSUSB results in "Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device"

Comment: That information is already in the OP: *Vendor= **05c6** ProdID= **1000** Rev=00.00* and that was exactly how I found the other questions. Please read again my previous comment.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Have you tried `modprobe usbserial` and/or `modprobe qcserial`? For me, `modprobe usbserial vendor=0x05c6 product=0x900e` created `/dev/ttyUSB0`. For you, `product=0x1000`.